# Placing strftime in rails each_value producing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to have the months from my DB display in long form (July) instead of as a number. It gives an error "undefined method `strftime' for 7:Fixnum". I'm not sure where to put it as I am new to rails.

```
def show
  @m = Model.all.order("date DESC")

  @months_in_year = @m.group_by{|x| x.date.year}
  @months_in_year.each_value {|months| months.map!{|m| m.date.month.strftime('%B')}.uniq!}
  @all_months = @months_in_year.values.sort



  respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render :action => :show }
      format.js
      format.json { render :json => { :month => @all_months } }
  end   
end
```

Comment: What error did you see?

Comment: undefined method `strftime' for 7:Fixnum

Comment: Show us the code producing the error, not the code before the error if you don't mind.

Comment: Try `m.date.strftime('%B')}.uniq!`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're seeing this error is because `strftime` works on `Date`, `Time`, and `TimeWithZone` objects. It does not work on integers. The `TimeWithZone` class [acts just like the ruby Time class](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/time_with_zone.rb#L22). Calling `.month` on a `TimeWithZone` [will return an Fixnum](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Time.html#method-i-month).

```
@months_in_year.each_value {|months| months.map!{|m| m.date.strftime('%B')} }
```

should give you what you're looking for.